# Is it possible to use Watir-Webdriver to interact with Polymer?

Tags: polymer, watir-webdriver

I just updated my Chrome browser (Version 50.0.2661.75) and have found that the chrome://downloads page has changed such that my automated tests can no longer interact with it. Previously, I had been using Watir-Webdriver to clear the downloads page, delete files from my machine, etc, without too much difficulty.

It looks like Google is using `Polymer` on this page, and

- there are new (to me) elements like `paper-button` that Watir-Webdriver doesn't recognize
- even `browser.img(:id, 'file-icon').present?` returns `false` when I
  can clearly see that the image is on the page.

Is automating a page made with Polymer (specifically the chrome://downloads page) a lost cause until changes are made to Watir-Webdriver, or is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: if you are consider JS for a solution to polymer integration see the PSK's main app.js   https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the download items are accessible in Javascript and that Watir [allows Javascript execution](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Browser:execute_script) (as @titusfortner pointed out), it's possible to automate the new Downloads page with Watir.

Note the shadow root elements (aka "local DOM" in Polymer) [can be queried with `$$`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#work-with-local-dom).

Here's an example Javascript that logs the icon presence and filename of each download item and removes the items from the list. Copy and paste the snippet into Chrome's console to test (verified in Chrome 49.0.2623.112 on OS X El Capitan).

```
(function() {
  var items = document
                .querySelector('downloads-manager')
                .$$('iron-list')
                .querySelectorAll('downloads-item');

  Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
    let hasIcon = typeof item.$$('#file-icon') !== 'undefined';
    console.log('hasIcon', hasIcon);

    let filename = item.$$('#file-link').textContent;
    console.log('filename', filename);

    item.$.remove.click();
  });
})();
```

**UPDATE:** I verified the Javascript with Watir-Webdriver in OS X (with ChromeDriver 2.21). It works the same as in the console for me (i.e., I see the console logs, and the download items are removed). Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Run the following commands in a new `irb` shell (copy+paste):

```rb
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

2. In the newly opened Chrome window, download several files to create some download items, and then open the *Downloads* tab.
3. Run the following commands in the `irb` shell (copy+paste):

```rb
script = "(function() {
  var items = document
                .querySelector('downloads-manager')
                .$$('iron-list')
                .querySelectorAll('downloads-item');

  Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
    let hasIcon = typeof item.$$('#file-icon') !== 'undefined';
    console.log('hasIcon', hasIcon);

    let filename = item.$$('#file-link').textContent;
    console.log('filename', filename);

    item.$.remove.click();
  });
})();"

b.execute_script(script)
```

3. Observe the *Downloads* tab no longer contains download items.
4. Open the Chrome console from the *Downloads* tab.
5. Observe the console shows several lines of `hasIcon true` and the filenames of the downloaded items.

Comment: I'll see if I can get this to work. I don't know much Javascript, and I'm getting a few syntax errors with your code. Tried it on the (Linux) Chrome version specified in my question and also on one closer to your version, though still Linux: 49.0.2623.110.

Comment: There was also a stray dot that caused a syntax error. Fixed now.

Comment: Ah, the stray dot seems to have been the crux of it. It cleared most of my downloads, strangely left a few, but this is a start. Thanks! I'll do a little more work before I select an answer.

Comment: Your script works in the console, but I'm having difficulty implementing it with Watir-Webdriver. Possibly because Watir-Webdriver isn't happy about Polymer, but definitely a contributing factor is my lack of solid Javascript skills. Hopefully I can get your idea to work for me--I need to do a few other things beyond what this script does. But I appreciate your help and have upvoted your answer.

Comment: I don't think Watir-Webdriver has an issue with Polymer, as I just verified the Javascript with it (see updated answer).

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, I lack Javascript skills. I tried to make it work on my own but was unable to. I actually thought I did exactly what you ended up suggesting in your updated answer, but obviously I did something different/wrong because it didn't work for me. Copying and pasting your updated answer: magic! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Google put the elements inside the Shadow-Dom, which isn't supported by Selenium/Watir/WebDriver spec (yet). There might a way to obtain the element via javascript (`browser.execute_script(<...>)`), but it is experimental at best still.

Comment: wow, given all the things that use webdriver, that change is going to bust a lot of automation the world over.   'thanks google'

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to automated a Polymer page, I found I was able to access the web elements by asking Polymer to use the shady dom by adding ?dom=shady in the URL. Like in the example on this page https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings:

```
http://example.com/test-app/index.html?dom=shady
```

Adding the dom parameter to request Polymer to use the shady dom may be worth a try.